# JSF h:commandLink action property not invoking the method, rather reloading the page

Tags: java, jsf-2, methods, xhtml

I have a method called *Remove*. It is present in all the rows of the h:dataTable. 
The dataTable entries are extracted from the database.

Code of the dataTable **along with the rest of the page**  is:

```
  <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                 template="/webpages/templates/MainTemplate.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="infomationPartOfBody">
     <h:form>
      <div class="infoContent">

          <div id="title">
              Employee's Schedule
              </div><br/>
          <div>Being the <b>administrator</b>, you can keep track of the work distribution amongst the employees of the organization.
          Just select the employee ID from the drop-down list to view the details.</div><br/><br/><br/>

        <div><table border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="8">


                <tr>
                    <td> <b><h:outputLabel value="Select Employee ID"/></b> </td>
                    <td>   

                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{empDutySchedBean.empID}">

                             <f:selectItems value="#{dropDownBean.dropItems}" />
                           </h:selectOneMenu>


                    </td>


                    <td> <h:commandButton class="button" id="allocateButton" value="View the Schedule" style="width: 100%" action="#{empDutySchedBean.viewEmpTask}"/>   </td> 
                </tr>

            </table>  </div> <br/><br/>

            <div class="empDutyInfo"> <table border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="8"  >
                <tr>
                    <td> <h:outputLabel
                         style="font-size: 20px;
                        color:#000000; border-bottom-style: groove;
                          text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #95D0CA; "    
                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="Employee Name: "/>  </td>
                    <td> <h:outputText class="items"

                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="#{empDutySchedBean.fullName}" /></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <h:outputLabel
                         style="font-size: 20px;
                        color:#000000; border-bottom-style: groove;
                          text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #95D0CA; "    
                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="Employee ID: "/>  </td>
                    <td> <h:outputText
                            class="items"
                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="#{empDutySchedBean.partOf}"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <h:outputLabel
                          style="font-size: 20px;
                        color:#000000; border-bottom-style: groove;
                          text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #95D0CA; "   

                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="Designation: "/>    </td>
                    <td> <h:outputText
                            class="items"
                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="# {empDutySchedBean.designation}"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <h:outputLabel
                         style="font-size: 20px;
                        color:#000000; border-bottom-style: groove;
                          text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #95D0CA; "    
                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="Gender: "/>    </td>
                    <td> <h:outputText
                            class="items"
                            rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="#{empDutySchedBean.gender}"/></td>
                </tr>

            </table>




            <h:dataTable value="#{empDutySchedBean.empDuty}" var="u" border="1" rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10"

        styleClass="infoTable" headerClass="dataTableHeader" rowClasses="dataTableRow" >



            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Task Allocated
                </f:facet>   
                #{u.subTaskID}
            </h:column>

                <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Task Description
                </f:facet>   
                #{u.taskDescription}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    From 
                </f:facet>   
                #{u.fromDate}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    To 
                </f:facet>   
                #{u.toDate}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
              <f:facet name="header">

              </f:facet>   
                <h:commandButton class="button" value="Remove Task" action="#{removeTaskBean.abc}"/>
           </h:column>


        </h:dataTable></div><br/> <br/></div>
       </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

[image]

What I want to do is, that when *Remove* is clicked for a particular row, that row gets deleted from the database and the page reloads with the updated table.

I am not sure if the *action* attribute of *Remove* button is correctly defined or not. I have tried passing parameter to the method: `action="#{removeTaskBean.taskRemove(u.subTaskID, empDutySchedBean.partOf)}`.

the `empDutySchedBean.partOf` is taken from

```
  <tr>
          <td> <h:outputLabel style="font-size: 20px;  color:#000000; border-bottom-style: groove;text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #95D0CA; " rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="Employee ID: "/>  </td>
           <td> <h:outputText class="items"rendered="#{empDutySchedBean.show}" value="#{empDutySchedBean.partOf}"/></td>
  </tr>
```

If you will look at the image, you will see that `{empDutySchedBean.partOf}` is retrieved from another method in another bean.

Also the method that is invoked by the *Remove* button is:

```
public void taskRemove(String id, String tID) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("in Bean: taskRemove() invoked");
    setTheempID(id);
    System.out.println("in RemoveTaskBean, the emp ID is  "+getTheempID());
    setTheTaskID(tID);
    System.out.println("subtask ID"+ getTheTaskID());
    setNoRowEffect(ts.removeEmpTask(getTheempID(), getTheTaskID()));
    System.out.println("in Bean: no of rows affected   "+getNoRowEffect());
 }
```

*How do i know if the method has not been called?* Well thats because the print statement `System.out.println("in Bean: taskRemove() invoked");` doesnt print on the output console of netBeans.

I am not sure if the was i am trying to extract the `id` and the `tID` is correct or not. I think it is not being able to know which `tID` i want to extract because there are somany in the table.

**Edit**
I have realized that tomcat server does not support parameter passing by default. So i learnt that i need to add **el-impl-2.2.jar** to my libraries. I have added that, Now the method invokes. But when i print the parameter passed on the output of netbeans it doesnt print anytg.  Now the problem has changed a bit. It has become about something else.

Comment: Check if you have such valid bean called "removeTaskBean" and it has that method "taskRemove" ?

Comment: yes i do have. If you see the method called `taskRemove()` above. Thats the same method. Do you think i have parametrized the method in `action` property correctly? i think the problem is there

Comment: @Jay check out the image to see if it helps :)

Comment: You post only a snippet of the page layout. You don't have nested forms or anything right?

Comment: I fail to understand where the problem is. Even if the method does nothing at all. It should atleast be invoked.

Comment: @Gimby actually i have the logout button which is the only thing placed in a form in the template file. When i use the template, i have redefined some components and added a form. So is it considered as nested forms? I dont think so

Comment: @Gimby i just tried invoking some other random method in the same bean. It didnt invoke either. It is just a simple method wid a print out statement. So i guess there is a problem with the **invoking**. Should i paste more code?

Comment: @Gimby check out. I have added the coding of the rest of the page as well.

Comment: I'd rather look at the HTML source and try to find something wonky in there. I said nested forms (read: a form inside a form) because that is a very easy way to completely scr*w up JSF. Its also against the HTML specifications. I see nothing wrong in the page layout, but it can still be the template that is causing issues. Also check the browser's javascript console to be sure that there are no errors there somewhere.

Comment: Another brainfart: what is in the web.xml? What servlet specification version do you define there?

Comment: @Gimby I m sure there is no problem with the template. It works just fine. Here is something *interesting*. I tried putting the button outside the dataTable. And it works! it invokes the `abc()` method. So there is a problem with the button being inside the dataTable. And there are no nested forms.

Comment: Very strange, never saw that myself. Although I tended to use h:commandLink in this particular design scenario. What can I say? Perhaps you're running an ancient version of JSF 2.x?

Comment: @Gimby I dont think so. Read the edit and see if you can help me debug now. :)

Comment: Not really. You're running Tomcat 7 or higher? That should have support for new-style EL (with parameters) out of the box. But you have to be sure to declare the proper servlet specification in the web.xml